# When and How was Homura's wish fulfilled?

Tags: madoka-magica

In ep. 10, Homura's wish is revelaed:

> "I want to redo my meeting with Kaname-san. Instead of being protected by her, I want to protect her!"

This wish forced her to go back in time and re-live the month since her meeting with Madoka 100-ish times.

But in the end of the main timeline (ep.12), it is still Madoka that saves the day

> by wishing to rescue all magic girls before they "completely" turn into witches.

Since the world was rebooted by Madoka's wish we briefly see events that happened during that month, such as

> Sayaka's despair for being unable be with Kamijou, only to be rescued by Madoka.

I won't address the Rebellion movie in this question body, but feel free to include it in the answers.

Since by the end of ep.12 it does not feel like Homura's wish was fulfilled, question remains:

Was it fulfilled, if yes, when and how?

Comment: Time travel stories always contain paradoxes. Don't think too hard about it.

Comment: @Euphoric Not in this case. It is stated that every time Homura goes back she (creates/arrives at) another timeline. So there is no causality nexus for paradox, regarding HER travels.

Comment: Is it possible that only the first part was considered her wish, so her wish was fulfilled just by gaining the ability to go back? Or maybe it's the standard Kyuubei fine print: "If your wish involves accomplishing something on your own, the Kyuubei cannot ensure or guarantee its fulfillment, and all risk thereof is assumed by the wishmaker."

Comment: @Euphoric But we're here to think way too hard about this stuff. That's the fun of it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to how Homura can still have her wish granted in Madoka's Universe, one reason could be, as [Euphoric said](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/35802/when-and-how-was-homuras-wish-fulfilled#comment48048_35802), it's a paradox. but then again we can say that for anything, it's more fun to see what we can infer from what we have seen, isn't it?

The second could be what I am going to call the ***Room of Origin*** (my term, not canon, since it has no name to my knowledge). We see the Room or Origin twice as being the center point of the universe being created. the first time was when Madoka recreated the universe and the second time was when Homura did it at the end of Rebellion (in Rebellion Homura says she's been there once before when the Incubator asks where they were). Since this is really ground zero for the start of the new universe we can make the assumption that a part of the old universe still exists inside the Room or Origin, serving as the basis.

The third reason could be that Homura retained her memories and abilities because she was key to creating Madoka's Universe. It was her terminating the timelines that compiles Madoka's Karmic Destiny that allowed her to become a god. In Homura's Universe Madoka regaining her memories would return her to becoming the full Law of Cycles once more and Sayaka retaining her memories initially could be because she is a part of the Law of Cycles as her secretary until Homura sealed them and probably sealed Nagisa before hand (since she did create a new life for Nagisa)

Answer (score 0):

Her wish was to protect Madoka, not for Madoka to be safe. It's open-ended and why she is able to take effective action to protect Madoka, even when it meant (Rebellion Story spoiler)

> rejecting salvation from an omnipresent arbitrarily-powerful deity and dragging a human avatar out of it

Her failures don't invalidate the wish because as long as she has the will to go on, she can rewind and keep protecting Madoka.